# Prove element of a set is positive or zero or negative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having trouble demonstrating the following:

Let $a \in S$, and denote by $P$ the set of elements such that $a\geq\epsilon$,  for some $ \epsilon > 0$

Prove that for all $a \in S \subset \mathbb{Q}$, either $a \in P$, $a=0$ or $-a\in P$.

$\textbf{My approach}$

I know that $a \notin P \implies a < \epsilon$, but this does not guarantee that $a=0$ or that $-a \in P$, since by the density of the rational numbers there should always be a value in between $\epsilon$ and $0$. I can't say that $-a > -\epsilon \implies -a \in P$ either. So I'm pretty much stuck here.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If you really mean that $P=\{\,a\in\mathbb Q\mid \forall \epsilon>0\colon a\ge \epsilon\,\}$, then $P=\emptyset$.

Comment: No, sorry, just corrected it, it's for some epsilon

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: $P$ is not empty. It is the set of positive rationals.

Comment: @David: I think you're first question was okay. It makes no sense after the edit. And what is $S$?

Answer (score 0):

***Hints***

1. $ P  = $ The set of Positive Real Numbers (Might need proving).
2. Every rational number is either positive, zero or negative.

To prove the first. Assume there exists $x \in A$ such that $x \le 0$. Then argue there cannot be a positive quantity $\epsilon $ which is less than or equal to $x$. Then pick any $x \gt 0$ and let $\epsilon = x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in P$ then $a\ge \epsilon>0$, so $a>0$. On the other hand, if $a>0$, we can let $\epsilon=a$ and find that $a\in P$. Hence $a\in P\iff a>0$.
Consequently, $-a\in P\iff -a>0\iff a<0$. By trichotomy, the claim follws.